# Linking CSS File with HTML Document In Different Directories On my Windows

Tags: html, css

I try to link style sheets in a file with html file in different directory.

At first html document and CSS file were in the same directory and it were working well, till I moved style to other directory.

```
<head>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/style1.css">
</head>
```

Comment: give the `href` path correctly. give the screenshot of your directory. try `href="styles/style1.css"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go back one directory back by `../`. This way go to parent folder of these two files. Then start to go into css file's directory.

`href="../styles/style1.css"`

Answer (score 0):

Its a bad approach for putting `styles` and `html` folder in different directory try to use them in same folder so that where ever your run your project either on server ,local or in different directory, it work well.

If you do that(in different folder on windows) its hard coded and in programming(whatever Lagrange it is) hard coded coding is not allowed.

Answer (score -1):

Well i think you only need:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style1.css">
</head>
```

Also you can use 'base' tag:

For more info : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp